# How do I use "pack/unpack" in Perl?

Tags: perl, unpack

My data is encoded as 64-bit network byte order when I parse it using the [Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29) language as following:

```
def unpack_string(str)
   binary = str.unpack('m*').first
   binary.unpack('G*')
end

my_array_of_floats = unpack_string(str)
```

How could I do the same thing using Perl's [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html)/[unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html)?

Comment: Thanks, I've already refered that doc. as shown in your link, but still cann't figure it out, could you give me more hints?

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the Ruby documentation,

- `m` is MIME base64 encoding.
- `G` is a double-precision, network (big-endian) byte order

Perl's `unpack` doesn't do [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), but [MIME::Base64](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MIME::Base64) does.

In Perl's `unpack`, `d` is a double precision. You can specify the endianness using `>`.

```
use MIME::Base64 qw( decode_base64 );
my @nums = unpack 'd>*', decode_base64 $str;
```

`>` was introduced in Perl 5.10.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did use MIME::Base64 to decode data to get binary data as you mentioned. also I have tried your suggestion, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Here is a sample data: `my $str1='eJxM3Xc8lt//OPDQosxoiYwWQlaavIiGklnaISQle932yF7Jyp5llS0lmSkpZaSozHprSDLa4/f+vc/5fu6X/56Pc65zXq9z7vu6zrVuYF/P4ty8sW8W/QP7+jkePFzFyOy+x+WSkDkDC9NTmH7SM8C+5w1y37t6z2fI/dOuf+WRh//KP5pEHmX/+F4YnN9vGST+wF9gUAFRTy74EH9aaclRCvHxr4B4SnIt93K4NJ1nTPxVcdR4Anx/JdH2fu5dMSaD2v97YOD5C6Y72Ixz+L4gzzt7JonxPzvwxOgrjn1AjrcLTL2NnBTdm9OJnFYiw6qEnPXYv3IEfOtdgPjKeF/dcwg6U0LLC7kURFZASF8fdbF0eM81CHl+lLp83+hICATdOk9945zGzjLwX'; it is double precison, network byte order, 64-bit decoded

Comment: since it has been compressed using zlib lib, so what i did before using unpack is : `<code> my $base64_decoded = decode_base64($str);
 my $uncompress_;
 my $input = \$base64_decoded;
 inflate $input => \$uncompress_; </code>`

Comment: Hi Ikegami, thanks for you reply, I updated my perl's version, and try it again, it works fine. thanks again!

Comment: @Peter Mortensen, The [spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2045) treats it as a regular word ("base64" unless at the beginning of a sentence). The actual value is case-insensitive.